# Moving Create React App folder breaks working app

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, create-react-app

I've created a basic React web app with `create-react-app` and it has the following structure after ejecting. Works just fine.

```
intended-app-home
  |- the-app
      |- config
      |- node_modules
      |- public
      |- scripts
      |- src
      |- package.json
  |- .eslintignore
  |- .eslintrc
  |- .gitignore
```

Now, I want to move the contents of `the-app` up a level, to the folder `intended-app-home`. When I do this, I get the following error when running `npm start`:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/index.js

  1:1  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


Error in ./src/components/Blah.js

  1:1  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

What am I missing? Is it not safe to assume that the app folder is portable?

Here are my `.eslintrc` contents:

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "strict": ["error", "global"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `.eslintrc`?

Comment: Added as Edit #1

Comment: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/462

Comment: @AndrewLi - This appears to fix my issue. Hooray. Go ahead and post as an answer to accept. But how do I explain why this ESLint config works without changes inside the `the-app` folder, but not outside it?

Comment: Wow... pretty much everything to do with ESLint is 'broken' when moving the contents of the app folder. For example, JSX wasn't being understood and had to add additional ESLint rules (`"react/jsx-uses-vars"`). Is it strange that ESLint seems so tightly coupled to the folder where the app currently resides?

Comment: See my answer. Basically, your `.eslintrc` overrides the ESLint config from CRA in `package.json`. To add new rules, don't create a new ESLint config file. Just edit the one in `package.json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the following to your `.eslintrc` as the error suggest:

```
"parserOptions": {
  "sourceType": "module"
}
```

Per [the ESLint documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options):

> - **`sourceType`** - set to `"script"` (default) or `"module"` if your code is in ECMAScript modules.

The thing is, in ECMAScript 2015, there are things such as scripts and modules. Scripts are just plain JavaScript files. Modules, on the other hand, are scripts that export data and/or import other modules. So, if you want to use `import` or `export`, you have to specify `"sourceType": "module"` so that ESLint can correctly parse your module code with [Espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree) and lint it.

Now onto why the error only happens when you move `the-app` contents up one level. By default, Create React App uses the following ESLint configuration for its projects, specified in `package.json`:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
}
```

So the ESLint configuration just extends the React App configuration. And if you look at the source for [`eslint-config-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-react-app), in [`index.js`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-react-app/index.js):

> ```
> parserOptions: {
>   ecmaVersion: 6,
>   sourceType: 'module',
>   ecmaFeatures: {
>     jsx: true,
>     generators: true,
>     experimentalObjectRestSpread: true,
>   },
> },
> ```

So, by default, Create React App's ESLint configuration sets `sourceType` to `module`. The problem arises when you try to move `the-app`'s contents up one level. Since your `.eslintrc` did *not* specify `sourceType`, the default value `script` is used. And since `.eslintrc` overrides the ESLint in the `package.json` from Create React App<sup>1</sup>, the error occurs as you cannot use `import` and `export` in scripts.

---

You shouldn't create a new ESLint configuration file if you want to add new rules. Instead, just edit the configuration already in `package.json`:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "react-app"],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "strict": ["error", "global"]
  }
}
```

Note that `eslint-config-react-app` already sets `env` for you.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you check [the ESLint source](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/afbea78d4b94839ec6d59d2c98321901aeb76313/conf/default-cli-options.js), the default CLI option is to use the `.eslintrc` if the file exists over `eslintConfig` in `package.json`, see the property `useEslintrc: true`. Thus the reason it is overridden.

Comment: What a terrific and clear answer. Deleting my extra, new `.eslintrc` file did the trick, leaving the config in `package.json` to do what it wanted anyway. However, the answer is really clear in describing how the `package.json` lint config was getting overridden in the top-level folder.

Comment: @changingrainbows I'm assuming you mean "isn't clear" instead of "is clear". If you check [the ESLint source](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/afbea78d4b94839ec6d59d2c98321901aeb76313/conf/default-cli-options.js), the default CLI option is to use the `.eslintrc` file exists over `eslintConfig` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

In case above didn't help, **deleting the ios/build folder** and running again worked for me.

i.e. from your new root folder

```
 rm -r ios/build
 npx react-native run-ios
```

Per answer in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18793