# React Native app created with init not working if i moved from one folder to other

Tags: reactjs, native

**Action:** Initially my app use to work as expected but after Moving react native app created on desktop to a different folder i am getting below error

**Error:** Runtime is not ready for debugging on simulator while running app from vscode using command `react-native run-ios`

**Tried:** `npm start` as well

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting your android, ios and node modules folder and run the following

```
1.> npm install // to get dependecies loaded
2.> react-native upgrade // to create ios and android folder
3.> react-native link // to link the libraries
4.> react-native run-android (or) > react-native run-ios
```

For react-native version 0.60 or more

```
1.> npm install // to get dependecies loaded
2.> react-native upgrade --legacy // to create ios and android folder
3.> react-native link // to link the libraries
4.> react-native run-android (or) > react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible dupe of [Moving Create React App folder breaks working app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576822)

---

In case above didn't help, **deleting the ios/build folder** and running again worked for me.

i.e. from your new root folder

```
 rm -r ios/build
 npx react-native run-ios
```

Per answer in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18793